# Vue shopping cart add to cart not working

Tags: api, vue.js, axios

I cannot see what i have done wrong, i am trying to add my products to my cart but i am not having any luck. How do i add to cart? i can figure out the delete and clear from understanding how to add to cart. i have read through some documentation and managed to get this far but now i am stuck.
i am not sure if i am targeting wrong or i have named something wrong. I used a normal array and it worked alright but i am trying to do it with an api now, does this change the methods?

```
<section>
            <div class ="container" >
            <div id="app" >
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12" >
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <!-- Cart -->
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Product</th>
                                        <th>Price</th>
                                        <th>Quantity</th>
                                        <th>Total</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr v-for="(product, index) in cart">
                                        <td>{{ item.productName }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ item.price }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ item.quantity }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ item.price * item.quantity }} Coins</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Shop -->
                        <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3" v-for="product in products" :key="product.id" >
                                    <div class="card" >
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <div class="product">
                                                <img :src="product.productImage" alt="Product Img">
                                                <h4 class="text-info">{{ product.productName }}</h4>                                            
                                                <h4 class="text-muted">{{ product.price }} Coins</h4>
                                                <p class="text-muted">{{ product.productDescription }}</p>
                                                <input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control" value="1">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="productName" value="{{productID}}">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="price" value="{{productID.price}}">
                                                <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" @click="addToCart" class="btn btn-primary btn-block fa-lg gradient-custom-2 mb-3"  value="Add to Cart">                                                    
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>                
    <script>
        var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                products: '',
                cart: []
            },
            methods: {
                getproducts: function () {
                    axios.get('http://localhost:8888/DevsDev2022/productAPI/products')
                    .then(function (response) {
                        app.products = response.data;
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                },
                addToCart: function (product) {
                        var cartItem = this.cart.find(item => item.productName === product.productName);
                        if (cartItem) {
                            cartItem.quantity++;
                        } else {
                            this.cart.push({
                                productName: product.productName,
                                price: product.price,
                                quantity: 1
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    removeFromCart: function (product) {
                        var cartItem = this.cart.find(item => item.productName === product.productName);
                        if (cartItem.quantity > 1) {
                            cartItem.quantity--;
                        } else {
                            this.cart.splice(this.cart.indexOf(cartItem), 1);
                        }
                    },
                    clearCart: function () {
                        this.cart = [];
                    }
                },
            mounted: function () {
                this.getproducts();
            }
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: You could try passing the product when you call `addToCart`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your template tag around your template